# Joint Effort control in Gazebo Sim

Tags: gazebo

I use Gazebo Garden (and ROS 2 humble) and wish to build a computed-torque controller, that directly outputs the torque to send to the motors.

### Desired behavior

According to the [JointController plugin](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1JointController.html) reference, the plugin is designed to perform velocity control.

The `<use_force_commands>` flag only tells that the plugins uses torque internally, through a PID. Without this flag it seems a pure velocity is sent to the motor, which emulates a perfect servo motor.

Is it possible to use this plugin - or another - to directly control the effort we set on the joint?
That would be equivalent to setting 0-gains and only use the PID feed-forward term but this one is assumed to be constant.

The only alternative would be using `ros control` but it seems way more complex as we just want to add arbitrary efforts on the joints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another plugin, namely [ApplyJointForce](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1ApplyJointForce.html), can actually be used for this type of torque control.

Our robot xacro now takes a `mode` argument in order to activate either `JointPositionController` (position), `JointController` (velocity) or `ApplyJointForce` (effort) and allow the corresponding type of control.